# Icon font not working on subdomains of multisite

Tags: multisite, subdomains, icon

I have a multi site installation consisting of the main domain and various subdomans.

The domain and subdomain all use the one theme however the icon font of the theme doesn't display/load an any of the subdomains.

Why are subdomains of my multi-site network failing?

Comment: Have a look at the url to the font that is being displayed in your code. It might be that not the full url is being used

Comment: @YobdDigital The full URL is not being used. Just the the file name.

Comment: @YobdDigital I edited the paths as full paths but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you provide a link to both sites?

Comment: @YobdDigital Thanks for your willingness to review the matter however it turns out the root of the issue was my CORS policy (see my answer below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The problem:

Console log:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at xxx. (Reason: CORS header
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

## The solution:

Add the following header to your .htaccess file:

```
# https://wordpress.org/support/topic/font-awesome-not-working?replies=8#post-4921179
# Allow icon font to load on subdomains of WordPress multisite install.

<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|woff)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

...before:

```
# END WordPress
```